# TareaHaskell.hs:36:69: error: parse error on input ')'

Tags: parsing, haskell, input

This is my  first time trying Haskell. I'm trying to make a function that takes an element and a list and removes the second appearance of the item. For example, if the element is `2` and the list is `[2,3,4,2,5,2]` the result would be `[2, 3, 4, 5, 2]`.

However I am getting this error:

```
TareaHaskell.hs:36:69: error: parse error on input ‘)’
   |
36 |     | ( (a == x) && not (isItIn x newList) ) = ( (let newList = x:[]) && (deleteSecond a xs) )
```

Code:

```
isItIn :: (Eq a ) => a -> [a] -> Bool
isItIn a [] = False
isItIn a (x:xs) = if a == x
                  then True
                  else isItIn a xs

deleteSecond :: (Eq a ) => a -> ( [a] -> [a] )
deleteSecond a [] = newList
deleteSecond a (x:xs)
    | ( (a == x) && not (isItIn x newList) ) = ( (let newList = x:[]) && (deleteSecond a xs) )
    | (a == x) && (isItIn x newList) = (deleteSecond a xs)
    | otherwise = let newList = x:[] && deleteSecond a xs
```

I read it might be a problem with the indentation however I already tried using spaces, moving it back and forth, and it still isn't working.
I am also using Notepad++ and Sublime to help with the indentation and nothing.

Comment: `deleteSecond a [] = newList` what is `newList` here?

Comment: A new new list that should be the answer, I tried to defined it with the `(let newList = x:[])` statement below

Comment: `let` without a corresponding `in` is invalid outside of a `do` expression.

Comment: @viga11 Aaaahhh! That sounds like you're trying to manage state! No no, think functionally!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the parser isn't expecting the `)` in this code:

```
(let newList = x:[])
```

because it's invalid in Haskell to have a `let` statement that isn't followed by `in`. (With the exception of inside a `do` block.)

It's really not clear to me what your actual intention is, but all `let` is for is to give a more complex expression a temporary name inside a block of code. A `let` statement without an accompanying `in` doesn't make any sense, and is causing your parse error here.

Comment: I was trying to make a new list and then add the element `x` of the original to that new list I was creating.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a little over complicated. If you simplified it'd be more clear where the problem is, but

```
let newList = x:[]
```

is only valid if the next symbol is `in`. The parser is complaining that you're trying to parenthesize it for no reason. A let..in statement is just a way of temporarily binding a name to a value for the purpose of the expression.

```
let var = value in expr
```

---

As far as the problem itself: this is pretty easy to solve with explicit recursion.

```
removeSecond :: (Eq a) -> [a] -> [a]
removeSecond = go False
  where go _     _      []     = []
        go True  needle (x:xs) | needle == x = xs
                               | otherwise   = x : go True needle xs
        go False needle (x:xs) | needle == x = x : go True needle xs
                               | otherwise   = x : go False needle xs
```